# How to select only first few words not lines of sentences?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the following snippet:

```
 implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $sentence), 0, 10));
```

The problem is that if there are two or 3 lines than it repeats the function and shows 10 words or etc per line.

How can i do it so it only selects the first 10 words from the first sentence and not repeat itself.

Comment: Can we get a code sample up on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: What you say doesn't make sense? Are you doing it per sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `$sentence` only contains the first line of whatever you're feeding it, before it ever gets to this line of code.

Comment: Well, since we have no idea what $sentence could even contain, I have no idea how you could make sure of it. Something you need to check out in your code, or post more of your code so that we can try to help.

Comment: I am just using the $row['notes']; in a variable and outputting.

Comment: Well there still could be other things wrong since we only see a little bit of your code, but @amindfv 's answer looks right to me. Or maybe instead of `split("[\n|\r]", $sentence);` use `split("[\n\r]", $sentence);` ? I'm not too sure.

Comment: Actually, split() is deprecated in newer versions of PHP, so you should probably use `explode("\n", $sentence)` or `explode("\r\n", $sentence)`, and then the same `implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $lines[0]), 0, 10));`.

Comment: split("[\n\r]", $sentence); kept it the same way.  let me try the other one.  by the way i am using nl2br on the $sentence... would it matter..

Comment: If you're using that beforehand, then it may matter. This is why you need to provide all the applicable code when you're posting. I'm going to say you're on your own for now. Good luck.

Comment: the implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $lines[0]), 0, 10)); solution only selects the first letter.

Answer (score 2):

```
$lines = split("[\n|\r]", $sentence);
implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $lines[0]), 0, 10));
```

First split into many lines, then do your action on only the first line.

Comment: It will output if you tell it to (with a print statement, or whatever you need)